# Split a token twice with different delimiter C Code

Tags: c, split, token

I am trying to split a token with 2 different delimiters, but using strtok() twice on the same string gives me unexpected results.
After the first strtok I would like to have:

```
0
1
2
3
4;5;6;7
8
9
10
```

After the second strtok:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Here is my code:

```
char *token;
x[0] = {0};
char str[1024] = "0,1,2,3,4;5;6;7,8,9,10;
token = strtok( str, ",');

printf("token is %s\n", token);


//Second 'split'

char *p = strtok (token, ';');
while (p != NULL)
{
    array[z++] = p;
    p = strtok (NULL, seps2);
}

for (int i = 0; i < count + 1; ++i) 
    printf("%s\n", array[i]);
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html): _On the first call to strtok(), the string to be parsed should be specified in str.  In each subsequent call that should parse the same string, str must be NULL._

Comment: What is `array`? what is `x`? what is `seps2`? ... and there are several syntax errors so the code can't compile. Please fix the code so that it can compile.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: For nested tokenization you might take a look at [strsep](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strsep) if it is available in your environment

Comment: When you declare a character array, e.g.  `char str[] = "0,1,2,3,4;5;6;7,8,9,10;` is sufficient to provide storage for the string (including the *nul-termianting* characters). If you need the additional `1004` characters, then, of course, `char str[1024] = ...` is fine (but I would recommend defining a constant, e.g. `#define MAXC 1024` and then `char str[MAXC] ...` in that case)

Answer (score 2):

The second argument of [`strtok()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) is a string *each character* of which is considered to be a delimiter when tokenizing the string.

So you can make your `strtok()` calls to be `strtok(str, ",;")` as in

```
char s[]="0,1,2,3,4;5;6;7,8,9,10";
for(char *tk = strtok(s, ",;"); tk!=NULL; tk=strtok(NULL, ",;"))
{
    printf("%s\n", tk);
}
```

Output in this case would be

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Note that `strtok()` would modify the original string.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a POSIX system, try [`strtok_r()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html) ([see ideone](https://ideone.com/MNtKQn)).

Otherwise ([see ideone](https://ideone.com/bQYRY5)) you need to save the results from `strtok(XXX, ",")` and apply `strtok(XXX, ";")` to each result separately.